# Get Header Authorization value of a login api (sent with username and password in json body) using php curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I am writing a code in PHP where i need to call and API (Sending username and password) and then fetch the authorization value.

I tried some solutions which are already there on stack but was not able to do the same

[image]

Can anyone please suggest a way around

This is one of the code i tried

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "HandleHeaderLine");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
function($curl, $header) use (&$headers)
      {
        $len = strlen($header);
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
        if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
          return $len;

        $headers[strtolower(trim($header[0]))][] = trim($header[1]);

        return $len;
      }
    );
```

Comment: So where is your function `HandleHeaderLine`? That `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
function($curl, $header) use (&$headers) ...` coming _after_ `$output = curl_exec($ch);` doesn't do anything, should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: How is removing the code you are having a problem with, making anything more clear? Edit rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You call your API before add the headers:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$headers = array(
   "X-Custom-Header: value",
   "X-Custom-Header: value"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    

$output = curl_exec($ch); //Call your api at end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the headers, I was trying to read the http header responses  from https url posting request to http API